# Drawing a custom view using UIBezierPath results in a non-symmetrical shape

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw an UIView with some 'curvy edges'.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

here's what I got:

[image]

Notice how the top right (TR) corner is not symmetrical to the bottom right (BR) corner ? The BR corner is very similar to what I want to achieve but I can't get the TR corner to align correctly (played around with bunch of different start and end angles).

here's the code:

```
struct Constants {
    static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15.0 // used for left-top and left-bottom curvature
    static let rightTipWidth: CGFloat = 40.0 // the max. width for the right tip thingy
    static let rightCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0 // the radius for the right tip
    static let rightEdgeRadius: CGFloat = 10.0 // the radius for the top right and bottom right curvature
}
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    // Initialize the path.
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    // starting point
    let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: 0.0)
    path.move(to: startingPoint)

    // create a center point for the arc for the top left corner
    let leftTopCircleCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: leftTopCircleCenterPoint, radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // move the path to the bottom left corner
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: frame.size.height - Constants.cornerRadius))

    // add the arc to bottom left
    let leftBottomCircleCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: frame.size.height - Constants.cornerRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: leftBottomCircleCenterPoint, radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // move along the bottom to the right edge - rightTipWidth
    let maxXRightEdge = frame.size.width - Constants.rightTipWidth
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: frame.size.height))

    // add a curve at the bottom before tipping up at 45 degrees
    let bottomRightEdgeControlPoint = CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: frame.size.height - Constants.rightEdgeRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: bottomRightEdgeControlPoint, radius: Constants.rightEdgeRadius, startAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 45.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // figure out the center for the right side curvature
    let rightMidPointY = frame.size.height / 2.0
    let halfRadius = (Constants.rightCornerRadius / 2.0)

    // move up till the mid point corner radius
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - Constants.rightCornerRadius, y: (rightMidPointY + halfRadius)))

    // the destination for the curve (end point of the curve)
    let rightEndPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - Constants.rightCornerRadius, y: (rightMidPointY - halfRadius))

    // figure out the right side tip's control point (See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624351-addquadcurve)
    let rightControlPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - halfRadius, y: rightMidPointY)

    // add the curve for the right side tip
    path.addQuadCurve(to: rightEndPoint, controlPoint: rightControlPoint)

    // move up at 45 degrees
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge + Constants.rightEdgeRadius, y: Constants.rightEdgeRadius))

    let topRightEdgeControlPoint = CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: Constants.rightEdgeRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: topRightEdgeControlPoint, radius: Constants.rightEdgeRadius, startAngle: 315.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false) // straight

    path.close()

    // Specify the fill color and apply it to the path.
    UIColor.orange.setFill()
    path.fill()

    // Specify a border (stroke) color.
    UIColor.orange.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}

extension BinaryInteger {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return CGFloat(Int(self)) * .pi / 180 }
}
```

Just a quick summary of my thought process:

- Create a bezierPath and move it to the startingPoint
- Add the LT (left-top) curve and move the line downards
- Move the line along the left edge and add the LB (left-bottom) curve
  and the move line along the bottom to the right edge
- Move the line till `frame.size.width - Constants.rightTipWidth`
- Add an arc with a center point at `x = currentPoint` and `y = height- rightEdgeRadius`
- Move the line up until `y = (height / 2.0) +
  (Constants.rightCornerRadius / 2.0)`
- Add the QuadCurve with an end point of `y = (height / 2.0) -
  (Constants.rightCornerRadius / 2.0)`
- Move the line up till `x = maxXRightEdge + Constants.rightEdgeRadius`
- Add the top right (TR) curve ---> resulting in a non-symmetrical
  curvature

Comment: You ever used Paintcode?

Comment: @agibson007 no but I just gave it a try. They are hardcoding the frames so it's kinda pointless in my case since my view will be of dynamic size.

Comment: You can make them dynamic by wrapping it in a frame and setting the spring or whatever they call them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another rendition:

```
@IBDesignable
open class PointerView: UIView {

    /// The left-top and left-bottom curvature
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat      = 15      { didSet { updatePath() } }

    /// The radius for the right tip
    @IBInspectable var rightCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10      { didSet { updatePath() } }

    /// The radius for the top right and bottom right curvature
    @IBInspectable var rightEdgeRadius: CGFloat   = 10      { didSet { updatePath() } }

    /// The fill color
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor         = .blue   { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor } }

    /// The stroke color
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor       = .clear  { didSet { shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor } }

    /// The angle of the tip
    @IBInspectable var angle: CGFloat             = 90      { didSet { updatePath() } }

    /// The line width
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat         = 0       { didSet { updatePath() } }

    /// The shape layer for the pointer
    private lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let _shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        _shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        _shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        _shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        return _shapeLayer
    }()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updatePath()
    }

    private func updatePath() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let offset = lineWidth / 2
        let boundingRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: offset, dy: offset)

        let arrowTop = CGPoint(x: boundingRect.maxX - boundingRect.height / 2 / tan(angle * .pi / 180 / 2), y: boundingRect.minY)
        let arrowRight = CGPoint(x: boundingRect.maxX, y: boundingRect.midY)
        let arrowBottom = CGPoint(x: boundingRect.maxX - boundingRect.height / 2 / tan(angle * .pi / 180 / 2), y: boundingRect.maxY)
        let start = CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX + cornerRadius, y: boundingRect.minY)

        // top left
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX, y: boundingRect.minY + cornerRadius), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX, y: boundingRect.minY))

        // left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX, y: boundingRect.maxY - cornerRadius))

        // lower left
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX + cornerRadius, y: boundingRect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.minX, y: boundingRect.maxY))

        // bottom
        path.addLine(to: calculate(from: path.currentPoint, to: arrowBottom, less: rightEdgeRadius))

        // bottom right (before tip)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: calculate(from: arrowRight, to: arrowBottom, less: rightEdgeRadius), controlPoint: arrowBottom)

        // bottom edge of tip
        path.addLine(to: calculate(from: path.currentPoint, to: arrowRight, less: rightCornerRadius))

        // tip
        path.addQuadCurve(to: calculate(from: arrowTop, to: arrowRight, less: rightCornerRadius), controlPoint: arrowRight)

        // top edge of tip
        path.addLine(to: calculate(from: path.currentPoint, to: arrowTop, less: rightEdgeRadius))

        // top right (after tip)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: calculate(from: start, to: arrowTop, less: rightEdgeRadius), controlPoint: arrowTop)

        path.close()

        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }

    /// Calculate some point between `startPoint` and `endPoint`, but `distance` from `endPoint
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - startPoint: The starting point.
    ///   - endPoint: The ending point.
    ///   - distance: Distance from the ending point
    /// - Returns: Returns the point that is `distance` from the `endPoint` as you travel from `startPoint` to `endPoint`.

    private func calculate(from startPoint: CGPoint, to endPoint: CGPoint, less distance: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let angle = atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x)
        let totalDistance = hypot(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x) - distance

        return CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + totalDistance * cos(angle),
                       y: startPoint.y + totalDistance * sin(angle))
    }
}
```

And because that is `@IBDesignable`, I can put it in a separate framework target and then optionally use it (and customize it) right in Interface Builder:

[image]

The only change I made in parameters was to not use the width of the tip, but rather the angle of the tip. That way, if the size changes as constraints (or whatever) change, it preserves the desired shape.

I also changed this to use a `CAShapeLayer` rather that a custom `draw(_:)` method to enjoy any efficiencies that Apple has built in to shape layers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation but I think it will be easy if you implemented it like that , that way you cam achieve symmetric shape perfectly

[image]

to draw a triangle , just tweak the positions of triangle points

```
 class TriangleView : UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
    context.closePath()

    context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.60)
    context.fillPath()
}
}
```

Comment: thanks but i've a curve at the bottom of the triangle. if you look at my original image you can see a curve. Using your code would result in a 45 degree with no curvature I believe (i haven't tested it yet).

Comment: round radius the usual view  and shift the 2 triangles to the left

Comment: that might work but I'm afraid if we change the width of the main view it may overlap the triangle and will cause issues in the future. I guess i could programmatically change the frame of the triangle but even then we've to match the tangent of the curve to the edge of the triangle otherwise it won't be a smooth transition. I'll use this technique if i can't do the original way (with one drawpath). Thanks

Comment: whenever you change the width of view , the 2 triangles will be shifted to right accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here, you forgot `halfRadius`

```
// move up at 45 degrees
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge + Constants.rightEdgeRadius, y: Constants.rightEdgeRadius - halfRadius))
```

Full code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    // Initialize the path.
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    // starting point
    let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: 0.0)
    path.move(to: startingPoint)

    // create a center point for the arc for the top left corner
    let leftTopCircleCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: Constants.cornerRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: leftTopCircleCenterPoint, radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // move the path to the bottom left corner
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: frame.size.height - Constants.cornerRadius))

    // add the arc to bottom left
    let leftBottomCircleCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: Constants.cornerRadius, y: frame.size.height - Constants.cornerRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: leftBottomCircleCenterPoint, radius: Constants.cornerRadius, startAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // move along the bottom to the right edge - rightTipWidth
    let maxXRightEdge = frame.size.width - Constants.rightTipWidth
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: frame.size.height))

    // add a curve at the bottom before tipping up at 45 degrees
    let bottomRightEdgeControlPoint = CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: frame.size.height - Constants.rightEdgeRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: bottomRightEdgeControlPoint, radius: Constants.rightEdgeRadius, startAngle: 90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 45.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)

    // figure out the center for the right side curvature
    let rightMidPointY = frame.size.height / 2.0
    let halfRadius = (Constants.rightCornerRadius / 2.0)

    // move up till the mid point corner radius
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - Constants.rightCornerRadius, y: (rightMidPointY + halfRadius)))

    // the destination for the curve (end point of the curve)
    let rightEndPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - Constants.rightCornerRadius, y: (rightMidPointY - halfRadius))

    // figure out the right side tip's control point (See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624351-addquadcurve)
    let rightControlPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - halfRadius, y: rightMidPointY)

    // add the curve for the right side tip
    path.addQuadCurve(to: rightEndPoint, controlPoint: rightControlPoint)

    // move up at 45 degrees
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge + Constants.rightEdgeRadius, y: Constants.rightEdgeRadius - halfRadius))

    let topRightEdgeControlPoint = CGPoint(x: maxXRightEdge, y: Constants.rightEdgeRadius)
    path.addArc(withCenter: topRightEdgeControlPoint, radius: Constants.rightEdgeRadius, startAngle: 315.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: false) // straight

    path.close()

    // Specify the fill color and apply it to the path.
    UIColor.orange.setFill()
    path.fill()

    // Specify a border (stroke) color.
    UIColor.orange.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

Comment: @newDeveloper it depends on the frame of the view. Height should be 50 points because you have 45 degrees angle and 40 points width of the tip. Which means height should be equal 40 * 2 (sides of triangle are equal) - 10 * 3 (corner radiuses) = 50

Comment: @newDeveloper You can change either those constants for radiuses or height of the view so that the equation is right